# $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n<x_0<b_n$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}[f(b_n)-f(a_n)]=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is a question I picked up from Royden's.

> Let $f$ be an increasing function on an open interval $I$. For $x_0\in I$ show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if there there exists two sequences {$a_n$}, {$b_n$} in $I$ such that $\forall n$, $a_n<x_0<b_n$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}[f(b_n)-f(a_n)]=0$

This is my attempt for the forward implication.

Suppose $f$ continuous at $x_0$ and that for each pairs of  sequences {$a_n$}, {$b_n$} in $I$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}[f(b_n)-f(a_n)]\neq 0$. Then there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $N\in \mathbb{N}$ , there exists a $n>N$ such that $|f(b_n)-f(a_n)|\geq \epsilon$.

Also, there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that $|f(b_n)-f(x_0)|<{\epsilon\over 2}$ and there exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that $|f(a_n)-f(x_0)|<{\epsilon\over 2}$ whenever $|b_n-x_0|<\delta_1$ and $|a_n-x_0|<\delta_2$.

Notice that $$|f(b_n)-f(a_n)|=|f(b_n)-f(x_0)+f(x_0)-f(a_n)|\leq |f(b_n)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0)-f(a_n)|<\epsilon$$ whenever  $|b_n-x_0|<\delta$ and $|a_n-x_0|<\delta$ where $\delta=$max{$\delta_1,\delta_2$}. We have arrived at a contradiction. Is this idea correct?

Comment: A possibly simpler approach:  If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $\lim f(a_n)=f(x_0)$ whenever $\lim a_n=x_0$.  (I hope you've seen this result in Royden.)  Thus *any* pair of sequences $a_n$, $b_n$ work provided they satisfy $a_n\to x_0$, $b_n\to x_0$, and $a_n<x_0<b_n$.